# SQL Script to Show Past Data Month by Month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I apologize if my question may be answered elsewhere, I am just not sure what to search to know if it has been answered elsewhere.  I am new to SQL, and have been trying to query a DB that shows a customers system uptime based in a percentage that exists in the DB table, and report it as an average for that month, as well as the past performance for the previous months.

For example, I take a month average and display it for each month, but then do for the past year based on current month (i.e., Mar, Feb, Jan, etc...) always exactly a year of past performance.

Here is my current script that I got to work for a month's average based on customers ID....I would now like to show the past years performance like this for each month:

SQL Query:

```
select   cast (avg("DATA_POINT_DATA"."VALUE") as int) as "UP_VALUE",
"DATA_POINT_DATA"."UPLOAD_DATA_ID" as "CUSTOMER_ID"
 from   "DB_TABLE"."DATA_POINT_DATA" "DATA_POINT_DATA",
    "DB_TABLE"."CALC_DATA" "CALC_DATA" 
 where   "DATA_POINT_DATA"."CALC_DATA_ID"="DATA_POINT_DATA"."ID"
  and    "CALC_DATA"."NAME" ='CustomerUp' 
   and   "DATA_POINT_DATA"."UPLOAD_DATA_ID" in ('123abc')
   and  "UPLOAD_TIME" between ('01-FEB-17') and ('28-FEB-17') 
   group by "DATA_POINT_DATA"."UPLOAD_DATA_ID";
```

Query Output:

```
UP_VALUE    CUSTOMER_ID
-------- --------------
     100         123abc
```

Expected Output:

```
MONTH    UP_VALUE    CUSTOMER_ID
----- ----------- --------------
FEB           100         123abc
JAN           100         123abc
DEC           100         123abc
NOV            90         123abc
OCT           100         123abc
SEP           100         123abc
AUG           100         123abc
JUL            89         123abc
JUN           100         123abc
MAY            75         123abc
APR           100         123abc
MAR           100         123abc
FEB            90         123abc
```

Comment: You can just select and group by the month from `upload_time`?

Comment: Alex, thanks for the reply.  Sorry to sound ignorant, but can you be more specific....SQL is fairly new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an aggregate `avg()` function call, and you are already grouping by the non-aggregate column in your select list. To get data for each month for the last year (up to the end of the previous month, it appears) you just need to include the month in the select list and group-by clauses too:

```
select to_char(trunc("UPLOAD_TIME", 'MM'), 'MON') as "MONTH",
  cast (avg("DATA_POINT_DATA"."VALUE") as int) as "UP_VALUE",
  "DATA_POINT_DATA"."UPLOAD_DATA_ID" as "CUSTOMER_ID"
from "DB_TABLE"."DATA_POINT_DATA" "DATA_POINT_DATA",
  "DB_TABLE"."CALC_DATA" "CALC_DATA" 
where "DATA_POINT_DATA"."CALC_DATA_ID"="DATA_POINT_DATA"."ID"
and "CALC_DATA"."NAME" ='CustomerUp' 
and "DATA_POINT_DATA"."UPLOAD_DATA_ID" in ('123abc')
and "UPLOAD_TIME" between ('01-MAR-16') and ('28-FEB-17') 
group by trunc("UPLOAD_TIME", 'MM'), "DATA_POINT_DATA"."UPLOAD_DATA_ID";
```

The expression `trunc("UPLOAD_TIME", 'MM')` gives you midnight on the first day of the month for that column value. That can be used for the group-by, so all dates in a month are treated as being on the same day, the first. In the select list that same expression can then be converted to a string showing just the month name. (I've assumed your session is English, but there's [a third argument to `to_char()` to handle that](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129) if not).

The line

```
where "DATA_POINT_DATA"."CALC_DATA_ID"="DATA_POINT_DATA"."ID"
```

looks odd, and at the moment you don't seem to have any real join conditions between the two tables; I suspect that was supposed to be:

```
where "DATA_POINT_DATA"."CALC_DATA_ID"="CALC_DATA"."ID"
```

but perhaps not.

You are relying on your session NLS settings when you do:

```
and  "UPLOAD_TIME" between ('01-FEB-17') and ('28-FEB-17')
```

You should use an explicit `to_date()` call and format mask, and preferably not assume the session language is English (which affects month name handling), but at least do:

```
and  "UPLOAD_TIME" between to_date('01-FEB-17', 'DD-MON-RR')
  and to_date('28-FEB-17', 'DD-MON-RR')
```

... but even here, it's netter to use 4-digit years, and if any of your column values have times after midnight you'll lose the data for anything like `2017-02-28 00:00:01`.

You also don't need to use double-quotes around all the object names here; and without them the case of the object names doesn't matter, which might make it a bit easier to read. You should also use ANSI join syntax; assuming the where-clause observation above is right, you could do:

```
select to_char(trunc(upload_time, 'MM'), 'MON') as month,
  cast (avg(data_point_data.value) as int) as up_value,
  data_point_data.upload_data_id as customer_id
from db_table.data_point_data
join db_table.calc_data
on data_point_data.calc_data_id=calc_data.id
where calc_data.name ='CustomerUp' 
and data_point_data.upload_data_id = '123abc'
and upload_time >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -12)
and upload_time < trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
group by trunc(upload_time, 'MM'), data_point_data.upload_data_id
order by trunc(upload_time, 'MM') desc;
```

For the date range I've based it on the current date, and used `>=` and `<` instead of `between`, to avoid issues with non-midnight times. You can see the values those expressions evaluate to with:

```
select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -12), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as from_time,
  to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as to_time
from dual;

FROM_TIME           TO_TIME            
------------------- -------------------
2016-03-01 00:00:00 2017-03-01 00:00:00
```

Finally, `cast(... as int)` is a bit unusual; depending on how you want decimal parts to be handled, you could also look at `trunc()`, `ceil()` or `floor()`.

Comment: Alex, I am trying the above, however I get the following error:  Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DATA_POINT_DATA"."ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @Fadiddy - that's what you have in the query in your question, and which I queried in my answer - should that be `"CALC_DATA"."ID"` ? (Something else I forgot to mention; you have prefixed most columns with the tables they come from, but not `upload_time` - it's better to be clear and consistent. Using shorter, but still meaningful, table aliases might be something to look into later too)

Comment: Alex, you were right, I mis-typed it....it works!  Thank you very much!

Comment: One other question Alex if I may please....say I wanted to always have a year of past performance regardless of new month....how would I write a function to basically take the current time and subtract a year?

Comment: That's what I showed at the end of my answer, using sysdate?

Comment: Alex, my mistake I meant current time as passed in as a parameter.  So, if a user selects a parameter field 'FROM_DATE' and 'TO_DATE', that the past year performance would be generated based on those parameters and not current time (sysdate).

Comment: @Fadiddy - replace sysdate with your 'to_date` value, hopefully via a bind variable, to get a year back from that; if you want to use `from_date` as well replace that 12-month calculation too using that value. Not clear if you want complete months - if not remove the trunc parts too. So maybe all the way back to: `and upload_time >= :from_date and upload_time < :to_date` or maybe `... < :to_date + 1`. How you translate your user-supplied values to bind variables depends on your application/client/etc.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks Alex!  I am now trying to figure out how to include the year with the 'MM' month in the output (i.e., DEC 2017, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add month to select and group by:

```
SELECT datepart(upload_time, DP_MONTH) as upload_month, Cast (Avg("data_point_data"."value") AS INT) AS "UP_VALUE", 
       "data_point_data"."upload_data_id" AS "CUSTOMER_ID" 
FROM   "DB_TABLE"."data_point_data" "DATA_POINT_DATA", 
       "DB_TABLE"."calc_data" "CALC_DATA" 
WHERE  "data_point_data"."calc_data_id" = "data_point_data"."id" 
       AND "calc_data"."name" = 'CustomerUp' 
       AND "data_point_data"."upload_data_id" IN ( '123abc' ) 
       AND "upload_time" BETWEEN ( '01-FEB-17' ) AND ( '28-FEB-17' ) 
GROUP  BY datepart(upload_time, DP_MONTH), "data_point_data"."upload_data_id";
```

Comment: Anand, I am trying the above, yet I get the following error:  

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DATEPART": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: `datepart` isn't an Oracle RDBMS function.

Comment: @AlexPoole, really? I got it from this page - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10530_01/doc/epm.931/html_esb_techref/maxl/dml/funcs/datepart.htm

Comment: Yes, really. That page is from the Essbase documenation, not the RDBMS docs. The docs.oracle.com site covers all of their products, which gets confusing as they have several DB products (like MySQL).

Comment: Oh ok wow, thank you! It's good to know although I can't believe Oracle will make you jump through hoops for this simple datetime functions.